# OpenBGP httpd.conf

Tags: openbsd, openbsd-httpd

How to redirect an http request to specific page using OpenBSD's `httpd`; for example, I'm serving up OpenBGPd `bgplg` like so in `httpd.conf`:

```
ext_addr="127.0.0.1"

server "www.example.conf" {
listen on $ext_addr port 80
        location "/cgi-bin/*" {
                fastcgi
                root ""
        }
}
```

How to make it possible to redirect www.example.com to www.example.com/cgi-bin/bgplg, rather than having to type exactly www.example.com/cgi-bin/bgplg.

I tried a few options but none seems to work. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use a simple `block return` redirect, it needs a specific `/` location block or it will infinitely loop *(noting that the location block `/` is without a wildcard so assets can bypass)*

```
server "www.example.conf" {
    listen on $ext_addr port 80
        location "/cgi-bin/*" {
                fastcgi
                root ""
        }

        location "/" {
                # 302 (Temporary) while testing
                # 301 (Permanent) when you're done & sure
                block return 302 "/cgi-bin/bgplg"
        }
}
```

---

Now, there is another trick that generally works: `root` is passed through to fastcgi as the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable, which is executed if it exists.

A side effect is that httpd doesn't set the `SCRIPT_NAME` which bgplg requires and thus doesn't work; but other scripts that don't rely on it, or gracefully handle this will work fine, (*and can either handle `/` alone, or be extended with pattern matching or `/*` as a catch-all*)

```
location "/" {
        fastcgi
        root "/cgi-bin/somescript"
}
```